# Evenly spaced holes inside of a ring with correct topology

Tags: modeling, vertices, topology

[image]

[image]

I’m trying to create one hole then array two sections of the 12 sided shape to achieve a smooth ring with six perfect holes. Struggling to understand how to do this with correct topology.

How can this be best achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get something good with your current topology, the top and bottom faces are going to create the bad pinching, and if you subdivide them your hole shape won't be circular anymore.

But you can try something like that:

[image]

Then give it *Array + Simpled Deform (Bend) + Subdivision Surface* modifiers:

[image]

Comment: After deformation, the circles aren't circles any more? Have you tweaked those?

Comment: Hello Robin, why shouldn't they be circles anymore? Could you please share your file?

Comment: Ahhh! OK .. [It depends on the origin](https://imgur.com/a/RLfQKMu) with respect to the _Bend_ . I'd left mine at the middle of the cube I started with.

Comment: @moonboots Great solution, thanks for your time.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for pointing that out!